# How to wait function call inside a function in Java, is it possible?

Tags: java, kotlin, callback, architecture

I'm working with a TCP server. For login action, I have a sendLogin and a receiveLogin functions, but I would like to have only one function to call like this.

```kotlin
fun login(login: String, pwd : String){
   sendLogin(login, pwd)
   onReceiveLogin((connected) => 
       updateUiLogin(connected)
   )
}
```

Is it possible ?

EDIT:
Here is my actual configuration.

AbstractSocket -> SocketImplemented -> MainActivity

I would like to add a repository between SocketImplemented and the MainActivity.

AbstractSocket.kt

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractSocket(private val host: String, private val port: Int) : AbstractSocketInterface {
    private var mOut: OutputStream? = null

    lateinit var dis: DataInputStream
    var packLeft: Int = 0

    var connected = false

    suspend fun init() {
        withContext(IO) {
            val socket = Socket()
            try {
                socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(host, port), 1000)
                val mIn: InputStream = socket.getInputStream()
                mOut = socket.getOutputStream()
                dis = DataInputStream(mIn)

                onSocketConnected(this@AbstractSocket)
                connected = true

                while (connected) {
                    onMessageReceived()
                    if (packLeft > 0) {
                        println("Class:${this.javaClass.simpleName}\nSkipping bytes. N: $packLeft")
                        dis.skipBytes(packLeft)
                    }
                    if (packLeft < 0) {
                        println("Overrun on packet reading!")
                        connected = false
                    }
                }
            } catch (se: SocketException) {
                println(
                        "Error + $se\n" +
                                "host:${host}\nport:${port}"
                )
                onSocketDisconnected(se)
            } catch (sto: SocketTimeoutException) {
                println(
                        "Error + $sto\n" +
                                "host:${host}\nport:${port}"
                )
                onSocketDisconnected(sto)
            } finally {
                socket.close()
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun sendMessage(message: ByteArray) {
        withContext(IO) {
            mOut?.write(message)
            mOut?.flush()
        }
    }
}

interface AbstractSocketInterface {
    suspend fun onSocketConnected(abstractSocket: AbstractSocket)
    suspend fun onSocketDisconnected(exception: Exception)
    suspend fun onMessageReceived()
}
```

ImplementedSocket.kt

```kotlin
class ServerSocket private constructor(private val login: String, private val password: String, private val listenPort: Int, host: String, port: Int) : AbstractSocket(host, port) {
    private val tag: String = this.javaClass.simpleName
    private lateinit var serverSocketInterface: ServerSocketInterface

    companion object {
        private var instance: ServerSocket? = null

        fun getInstance(login: String, password: String, listenPort: Int, host: String, port: Int): ServerSocket {
            if (instance == null)  // NOT thread safe!
                instance = ServerSocket(login, password, listenPort, host, port)

            return instance!!
        }
    }

    override suspend fun onMessageReceived() {
        this.packLeft = readInt()
        val code = readInt()
        println("Received: Message code:" + code + " Packet Size:" + (this.packLeft + 4))

        when (code) {
            1 -> receiveLogin()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun receiveLogin() {
        if (readBoolean()) {
            val greeting = readString()
            val ip = readInt()
            println("Logged In.")
            serverSocketInterface.onLogin(1, "connected", ip.toString())
        } else {
            val reason: String = readString()
            this.connected = false
            println("Login Failed:$reason")
        }
    }


   
    private suspend fun login(login: String, pwd: String) {
        try {
            sendMessage(ByteMessage().write32(1)
                    .writeStr(login)
                    .writeStr(pwd)
                    .write32(160)
                    .writeStr(Bytes.md5(login + pwd))
                    .write32(1)
                    .buff)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun setServerSocketInterface(callback: ServerSocketInterface) {
        serverSocketInterface = callback
    }

    interface ServerSocketInterface {
        suspend fun onLogin(connected: Int, greeting: String, ipAddress: String) {}
    }

    override suspend fun onSocketConnected(abstractSocket : AbstractSocket) {
        abstractSocket as ServerSocket
        login(login, password)
        setListenPort(listenPort)
    }

    override suspend fun onSocketDisconnected(exception: Exception) {
        Log.w(tag, "Disconnected from Server")
        withContext(IO) {
            Log.i(tag, "Trying to reconnect...")
            this@ServerSocket.init()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ServerSocket.ServerSocketInterface {
    /* Managers */
    private lateinit var serverClient: ServerSocket

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                launch(CoroutineName("ServerSocket")) {
                    serverClient = ServerSocket.getInstance(
                            "login",
                            "password",
                            "listenPort",
                            "host",
                            "port")
                    serverClient.setServerSocketInterface(this@MainActivity)
                    serverClient.init()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        serverClient.stop()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        finish()
    }

    /* SERVER SOCKET METHODS */
    override suspend fun onLogin(connected: Int, greeting: String, ipAddress: String) {
        withContext(Main) {
            if (connected == 1) Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            else Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Not Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

So now I want to instead of call serverSocket methods directly, call a repository to get the login status.

Comment: You're probably looking for coroutines.

Comment: In fact, I already use coroutines. When my program is launched I send a sendLogin message, and when the server respond the receiveLogin function is fired. I was just asking myself if it's possible to join them. Because I want to implement repository pattern and in the android developpers example by Google. The ViewModels call only a single method to update their UI (login in my case).

Comment: The example above is like a callback, although the `onReceiveLogin` should be a parameter of the `sendLogin` function. Coroutines would let you place the function calls sequentially without nesting them as callbacks. Maybe you can show us how you're doing it now so we can see what needs to change to get what you want.

Comment: Yes of course, i'm gonna edit the main message